# How to have getopts functionality when just calling another function within the file

Tags: shell, getopts

I'd like to have named parameters for my functions.

I seem to only be able to use GETOPTS for the main function called from the command line.

If I have multiple functions within one file is there any way I can get the same sort of functionality (named parameters) when calling other functions ?

e.g. the following does not seem to work:

```sh
$ cat getops_example.sh 
function usage {
  echo 'here'
}

function my_test {
while getopts ":s:p:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        s)
            s=${OPTARG}
            ((s == 45 || s == 90)) || usage
            ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
}
my_test 11 20
echo "s was $s"
echo "p was $p"
$

$ ./getops_example.sh -s 10 -p 20
s was 
p was
```

Comment: You need to make sure you do `OPTIND=1` preceding *every set of parameters* you want to work with. So if you do `getopts...` for your script args and then attempt to do `getopts` within a function, reset `$OPTIND` before each `getopts` processing loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not work because you pass parameters to your program but inside the program you call your function `my_test` without the option flags `-s` and `-p` resp. Depending what you actually want, use either

```
my_test -s 11 -p 20
```

or pass the arguments from outside and call your function as

```
my_test "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks.  What if the values themselves are not determined until the actual call.  This is what I am looking for (I should have been clearer in my example, was trying to give a simple example).

Comment: Michael, for variable values passed from outside use the second form of my answer.